# Get unique userId and product details from Google Analytics API custom report

Tags: php, google-analytics

I need to generate a custom report with the details of unique userId, productSku, productName, pagePath, hostName using the google analytics api.

I am referring this document, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

My other references,
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

It is providing me the results of user sessions, pageviews, hostname, productPath but I am not able to get the unique userId or the product details such as productSKU or productName.

I need your help on this API reference. Is this the core reference what I am referring and any suggestions/reference to get the custom report with the details as I needed.

Programming Language used: PHP

Thanks

Comment: Are you storing user ID yourself as a custom dimension? As far as I know, standard user ID and client ID are not available through the API. Also, you could check the Query Builder (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to see, if your desired query can be built and run with the selected dimensions and metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the response @kgrg 

I have checked the Query Builder, it is useful. I like to know how to get the visitors Id or their IP to know who visited our website.